# How can I enable the HTTP/3 (QUIC) in HAProxy?

Tags: configuration, haproxy, quic, http3

I found the fact that HAProxy 2.3 higher supports HTTP/3 (QUIC) through **[this link](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/announcing-haproxy-2-3/#connection-improvements)**.

**I’d like to know how to enable HTTP/3 (QUIC) in HAProxy.**
I can’t find any data related to this anywhere.

I already downloaded the latest HAProxy source (v2.4-dev5) and built it with USE_QUIC=1.

Any suggestions would be great!
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are mistaken as to the current level of support. From [the announcement of v2.4-dev5](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg39364.html):

> Fred's experimental QUIC code made its entrance! OK OK OK please calm
> down, it's just a part of the code that's needed to get merged to
> continue the required infrastructure changes and there is absolutely
> nothing functional at this step. I think at best it will handle a
> handshake.